# How to read int,text and double from a file and store it into an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, string

What I am trying to do is read a text file which has this lines

232131231, random name, 23.3232

I only know how to read it as a String of the whole line. I don't know how to read them individually. This is my test codes.

main

```
   public class JavaApplication9 
{
    int value1;
    String value2;
    double value3;
    ArrayList<String> toBeSplit = new ArrayList(); 
    String[] split;
    ArrayList <Inventory> productList = new ArrayList<> ();

    public long ReadFile(String sfile) throws IOException 
            {       
                int x = 0;
                File inFile = new File(sfile);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
                String sline = null;
                while ((sline=reader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        toBeSplit.add(x,sline);
                        x++;
                    }
                reader.close();  
                return inFile.length();
            }

    public void splitString ()
    {   
        int a = 0;
        while (a<toBeSplit.size())
        {
            split = toBeSplit.get(a).split(",");            
            value1 = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            value2 = split[1];
            value3 = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
            productList.add(new Inventory (value1,value2,value3));
            a++;
        }
    }

    public void OutputLines ()
    {
         for (Inventory e : productList)
        {
            System.out.println (e.getBarcode() +"\t"+ e.getName()+"\t"+ e.getPrice());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        try
        {
            JavaApplication9 instance = new JavaApplication9 ();
            instance.ReadFile("Products (1).csv");
            instance.splitString();
            instance.OutputLines();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print ("Error");
        }
    } 
}
```

and my Inventory class

```
    public class Inventory
{
    int barcode;
    String name;
    double price;

   public Inventory (int bars,String pname,double prices)
    {
        barcode = bars;
        name = pname;
        price = prices;
    }

    public int getBarcode ()
    {
        return barcode;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice ()
    {
        return price;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split(String regex)` to split the string. (See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) for `split()`)
Then you can individually parse each value in the way you want it.

Here is an example using your data:

```
String toBeSplit = "232131231, random name, 23.3232";
String[] split = toBeSplit.split(",");
int value1 = Integer.parseint(split[0].trim());
String value2 = split[1].trim();
double value3 = Double.parseDouble(split[2].trim());
```

I use `trim()` (See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) for `trim()`) to get rid of the white space left behind after splitting.

Here's another way to do it without `trim()`: (Just add a space inside the split regex)

```
String toBeSplit = "232131231, random name, 23.3232";
String[] split = toBeSplit.split(", ");
int value1 = Integer.parseint(split[0]);
String value2 = split[1];
double value3 = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
```

Comment: Hey, I've did what you said. For some reason the program doesn't run. 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "01001010100011"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.splitString(JavaApplication9.java:36)
 at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.main(JavaApplication9.java:58)

Comment: @ZhiJTeoh the maximum value for an int is 2,147,483,647. This is because an int can only store 32 bytes. You are trying to store the number 1001010100011 (leading zeros are cut out when parsing int) which is much larger than 2147483647. Try Long.parseLong(String) and set the variable type to long. longs are 64 bits, and can store up to 9223372036854775807.

Comment: yup I figured it out too. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split(String regex)` for this.
Consider this simple example :

```
String mystr = "232131231, random name, 23.3232";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(mystr.split(", "));
for(String str : list){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

**Output :**

```
232131231
random name
23.3232
```

If you wanted to get list as `ArrayList` particularly, you can use `ArrayList(Collection list)` version of `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(mystr.split(", ")));
```